# Checking for empty or null JToken in a JObject

Tags: c#, sql, json.net

I have the following...

```
JArray clients = (JArray)clientsParsed["objects"];

foreach (JObject item in clients.Children())
{
    // etc.. SQL params stuff...
    command.Parameters["@MyParameter"].Value = JTokenToSql(item["thisParameter"]);
}
```

`JTokenToSql` looks like this...

```
public static object JTokenToSql(JToken obj)
{
    if (obj.Any())
        return (object)obj;
    else
        return (object)DBNull.Value;
}
```

I have tried `((JObject)obj).Count` also.. But doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

To check whether a property exists on a `JObject`, you can use the square bracket syntax and see whether the result is null or not.  If the property exists, a `JToken` will be always be returned (even if it has the value `null` in the JSON).

```
JToken token = jObject["param"];
if (token != null)
{
    // the "param" property exists
}
```

If you have a `JToken` in hand and you want to see if it is non-empty, well, that depends on what type of `JToken` it is and how you define "empty".  I usually use an extension method like this:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this JToken token)
    {
        return (token == null) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.String && token.ToString() == String.Empty) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make it extension method like: 

public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this JToken token) { ... } 

to use like 

JToken token = jObject["param"];
bool empty = token.IsNullOrEmpty()

Comment: Could you not `ToSrting` the `JToken` and check `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`? (After checking the `JToken` is not null of course)

Comment: @CodeBlend That won't work for an object or an array -- the serialized versions of those when empty are `{}` and `[]` respectively.

Comment: I would add Property checking:
   return (token == null) ||
                   (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues) ||
                   (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && !token.HasValues) ||
                   (token.Type == JTokenType.String && token.ToString() == String.Empty) ||
                   (token.Type == JTokenType.Null) ||
                   (token.Type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)token).Value.ToString() == string.Empty);

Comment: if a ".Property" notation should be used then `JToken token = jObject["param"];` could be written as `JToken token = jObject.Property("param")?.Value;`.

Answer (score 88):

You can proceed as follows to check whether a `JToken` value is `null`.

```
JToken token = jObject["key"];

if(token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
{
    // Do your logic
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, due to empty paramters returning a null type that passes a typical == null comparison. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is also a type - JTokenType.Undefined.

This check must be included in @Brian Rogers answer.

```
token.Type == JTokenType.Undefined
```

Comment: if it must be included in brians answer then id suggest you to post it as a comment in such answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can now in C# 6+ try to directly access with the [null-conditional access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?[]`.

```
    foreach (JObject item in clients.Children())
    {
        // value will be null if access fails
        var value = (string)item?["thisParameter"]?["anotherNode"]?["oneMoreNestedNode"];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As of C# 7 you could also use this:

```
if (clientsParsed["objects"] is JArray clients) 
{
    foreach (JObject item in clients.Children())
    {
        if (item["thisParameter"] as JToken itemToken) 
        {
            command.Parameters["@MyParameter"].Value = JTokenToSql(itemToken);
        }
    }
}
```

The is Operator checks the Type and if its corrects the Value is inside the clients variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to convert JToken to JArray:

```
static public JArray convertToJArray(JToken obj)
{
    // if ((obj).Type == JTokenType.Null) --> You can check if it's null here

    if ((obj).Type == JTokenType.Array)
        return (JArray)(obj);
    else
        return new JArray(); // this will return an empty JArray
}
```