# Check if json object is exists

Tags: c#, json.net

I'd like to check if the json object deserialized using Newtonsoft is empty.
I am using this code which feels a little hacky:

```
try{
dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
dynamic content = jsonObject.content.important;

 if (((JObject)content).ToString() != "{}"){ // inspecting if "imporant" has value
  // do stuff
  }
}catch(Exception e){
  // handle error
}
```

Is there a more "stylist" approach to inspecting if object exists?

Comment: JObject are dictionaries, you can look at the Count properties, which would be 0 if the object is empty.

Comment: You can use `JsonExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24067483) to [Checking for empty/null JToken in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24066400).  In fact this looks like a duplicate, agree?

Answer (score 3):

You can check count of `JTokens` available in `JObject content`. It will return `0`, if `JObject` is empty. Like,

```
try
{
    dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
    dynamic content = jsonObject.content.important;

    if (((JObject)content).Count > 0){ // inspecting if "imporant" has value
        // do stuff
      }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the content of the `jsonString` string variable before you deserialize it. You're overcomplicating things by deserializing, then serializing, then comparing.

A JSON object *always* starts and ends with `{` / `}`, and if you mean that an "empty" object is an object that has no properties within, then you're checking if the string value is equal to `{}`.

```
if (jsonString.Trim() == "{}")
{
   // object is empty
}
else
{
   // do deserialization 
}
```

The `Trim()` is put in just in case there is whitespace surrounding the brackets.

Note you'll have 2 edge cases here:

1. If there is whitespace between the brackets this code will think it's not empty, which is wrong.
2. This doesn't care if the string is valid JSON or not.

Comment: For 1 you can just use string.Replace instead of trim

Comment: @DetectivePikachu true, problem is that you'll need to replace every whitespace unicode character, and that's such an edge case that I don't want to get into it.

Comment: @gunr2171, OP does not want to check that root node is empty or not. He is trying to check JObject `jsonObject.content.important` contains any `JToken` or not. Kindly check OP's code `dynamic content = jsonObject.content.important;`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar you're totally correct. Didn't realise that myself until much after I posted this. Uh, I'll leave this post here for a bit longer than probably delete it later.