# Exclude null JValues from JSON response C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Having this JSON structure :

```
[
  {
    "Id": 885758,
    "IssueId": 611932,
    "Pinpoint": {
      "Name": null,
      "Position": {
        "X": -32.452857971191406,
        "Y": -14.971426010131836,
        "Z": 9.111014366149902
      },
      "Element1": null,
      "Element2": null
    }
  },
  {
    "Id": 885764,
    "IssueId": 611932,
    "Pinpoint": {
      "Name": null,
      "Position": {
        "X": -21.042057037353516,
        "Y": -21.742080688476562,
        "Z": 7.72857141494751
      },
      "Element1": null,
      "Element2": null
    },
  },
  {
    "Id": 885765,
    "IssueId": 611932,
    "Pinpoint": null
  }
]
```

I want to be able to obtain a List of JToken containing all `Pinpoints` that are not `null`
So basically something like this :

```
  {
    "Pinpoint": {
      "Name": null,
      "Position": {
        "X": -32.452857971191406,
        "Y": -14.971426010131836,
        "Z": 9.111014366149902
      },
      "Element1": null,
      "Element2": null
    }
  },
  {
    "Pinpoint": {
      "Name": null,
      "Position": {
        "X": -21.042057037353516,
        "Y": -21.742080688476562,
        "Z": 7.72857141494751
      },
      "Element1": null,
      "Element2": null
    }
  }
```

Image here of what a normal LINQ select without the where condition returns :
[image]

This is what I tried so far with related errors / exceptions :

```cs
//Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue
List<JToken> results = JArray.Parse(response.Content)
    .Select(x => x["Pinpoint"])
    .Where(x => x["Pinpoint"] != null)
    .ToList();

//Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
List<JToken> results = JArray.Parse(response.Content)
    .Select(x => x["Pinpoint"])
    .Where(x => x["Pinpoint"].HasValues)
    .ToList();

//Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
List<JToken> results = JArray.Parse(response.Content)
    .Select(x => x["Pinpoint"])
    .Where(x => x["Pinpoint"].Type != JTokenType.Null)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Does [Checking for empty or null JToken in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24066400) answer your question?

Comment: Errors are shown in the last **C# code block** see the comments. And no unfortunately it doesn't answer my question I can't make it work.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Comment: You need to put your `Where` clauses before your `Select` clause.  Once you've done `.Select(x => x["Pinpoint"])` your current item will be the value of `x["Pinpoint"]` so you can't do `x => x["Pinpoint"] != null` subsequently.  Or keep the `Where` clause first and do `.Where(p => !p.IsNullOrEmpty())` next, where `IsNullOrEmpty()` is from the linked question [Checking for empty or null JToken in a JObject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24066400).

Comment: Demo of using Brian Roger's `JsonExtensions.IsNullOrEmpty(this JToken token)` here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/INCWaq.  Do you need a separate answer or is a duplicate OK?

Comment: You can mark it as duplicate ty for the answer! However, could you explain why 
`x["Pinpoint"].Type !=null` doesn't work but `x["Pinpoint"].Type != JTokenType.Null` does achieve what I want? Also if im selecting the value of `x["Pinpoint"]` why can't I check for null directly ? Im still quite confused.

Comment: A null `JToken` will be returned when the value isn't present at all in the JSON.  A non-null `JToken` will be returned with type `JTokenType.Null` when the value was found in the JSON but the value itself was null.  I.e. if you do `x["Pinpoint"]` then if your JSON object looks like `{}` you will get back null but if your JSON object looks like `{"Pinpoint":null}` you will get back a `JValue` with `JTokenType.Null`. So you must check for both.  For details see [Strange behavior in json.net: why is a null JToken replaced with a non-null value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51777115/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
List<JObject> pinPoints = JArray.Parse(json).Where(p => (p["Pinpoint"] as JObject) != null)
.Select(p => (JObject)p["Pinpoint"]).ToList();
```

UPDATE

thanks to @dbc, there is a shorthand

```
JArray.Parse(json).Select(p => p["Pinpoint"]).OfType<JObject>().ToList();
```

Comment: `JArray.Parse(json).Select(p => p["Pinpoint"]).OfType<JObject>().ToList()` would work also and avoid doing `p["Pinpoint"]` twice.

Comment: @dbc Thank you! It is really interesting syntax. I will certainly use it in the future.

Comment: I removed the cast from inside the `Select(p => p["Pinpoint"])` because, if `p["Pinpoint"]` is a `JValue` with `JTokenType.Null`, it will throw an exception.  `OfType()` will filter them (as well as the actual null values) out later.